# Run Php Code in Linux

Tags: php, linux, shell

I would like to run some php code in my linux scripts to do some automation.I have searched on Google but I can't find any resources on it.Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
<?php echo "this is a test "?>
```

Error Message:syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: `/path/to/php -q filename.php`

Comment: you need to clean up your file: `<?php echo "this is a test"; ?>` also remove the `#!/bin/bash` and try what @AbraCadaver said, if that doesn't work, remove the line and just run `php /path/to/your/php/file.php`

Comment: You understand that `#!/bin/bash` means that the script should be run with `bash`, not `php`, don't you? What did you think the shebang line is for if not to specify the interpreter?

Comment: Also, you would need to make the file.php executable to use this method.  Or use @Barmar 's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your script using command in bash on linux:

```
php /path/to/file.php
```

also you can put it into some bash script.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'foo';
```

use `which php` to find out where your php interpreter is hidden and make sure you can execute your file `chmod u+x foo.php`